# Spring MVC - Distributed Database Transaction

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, concurrency, distributed

I'm currently developing a web application using Spring MVC (without Maven).
What I need is to create a distributed transaction between two local databases, so that the code will update all of them in (theoretically) a 2phase commit.

Now, since I'm doing it for a school project, I'm in a simple environment which needs only to take a row from a table in one db and put it in a table on the other db, of course atomically (theoretically, such a transaction should be distributed because I'm using two different databases and not only one).

My question is, how can I deploy a Spring bean that firstly connects to both MySQL databases and then does that distributed transaction? Should I use some external library or could I achieve all with only using the Spring framework? In which case, could you please kindly link me an example or a guide to do this?

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Spring has an interface PlatformTransactionManager which is an
  abstraction And it has many implementations like
  DataSourceTransactionManager,HibernateTransactionManager etc.
- Since you are using distributed transactions so you need to use
  JTATransactionManager
- These TransactionManagers provided by spring
  are wrapper around the implementations provided by other frameworks
- Now in case of JTA , you would be using either an application server
  or a standalone JTA implementation like Atomikos
- Following are the steps :-
- Configure Transaction Manager in spring using application server 
  or standalone JTA implementation
- Enable Transaction Management in spring
- And then configure in your code the @Transactional annotation above 
  your method
- Have a look at following links
- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html
- http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-jta-multiple-resource-transactions-in-tomcat-with-atomikos-example

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to follow and understand the guides that you have linked. Thanks again for your help :D